Why is my svchost local address shown as “host-87-0-105-0.retail.telecomitalia.it?”
I checked TCPView on Windows 10 and one of the svchost processes for the local host is shown as:
# host-87-0-105-0.retail.telecomitalia.it

svchost.exe,1136,UDPv6,,host-87-0-105-0.retail.telecomitalia.it,546,*,,30/07/2024 15:42:10,Dhcp,,,,

 Does anyone have any idea what that could be (I am not in Italy and never have been)?

That looks to be the DNS name your ISP has associated with your IP address. does that seem reasonable? if you run nslookup <your public IP> does the name returned match it?

Are you using a VPN? If so, that might be its host at the other end.

Some companies will use whatever IP address range they want, even if owned by someone else which they will then let it go through CGNAT. In case anyone says I am talking rubbish, I worked for a UK bank (part of a supermarket chain) that did this, and it just so happened that the range they used, was used by another UK bank which we needed to connect to. We had to run NAT in both directions.

I don't have a VPN. I am using a Huawey MiFi dongle (E5577C). I did some experiments for a while and found out that it actually works randomly. I am getting IPs from Australia (Cloudflare), France, Google, Canada, Germany, and occasionally my own IP provider, but that's very rare. I just want to understand what this means and if it's normal behavior. Thank you.

svchost.exe,6256,UDPv6,,modemcable001.96-176-173.mc.videotron.ca,546,*,,30/07/2024 18:50:21,Dhcp,,,,
svchost.exe,6256,UDPv6,,ip-091-089-254-144.um28.pools.vodafone-ip.de,546,*,,30/07/2024 20:43:55,Dhcp,,,,
svchost.exe,6256,UDPv6,,0.46.0.34.bc.googleusercontent.com,546,*,,30/07/2024 19:30:28,Dhcp,,,,

If you're using a VPN, yes, it is probably normal and expected. Though, I would expect someone using a VPN to be aware of this aspect of VPN usage, as misuse of a VPN can be pretty bad.

I don't use any vpn at all.
